# Модуль translate неправильно переводит строки

Tags: python

Есть задача: распарсить `json` файл в `excel` таблицу. Нужно циклом пройтись по `json`, взять оттуда каждый ключ и перевести с английского на русский. Далее переведенный текст записать в `excel` таблицу. Для решения задачи выбрал модуль `translate`. Однако, он выдавал ошибку `Runtime Error`. Прогуглил, написали, что проблема в том, что модуль видит пустую строку, пытается перевести и выкидывает эту ошибку (хоть в `json` нету пустых значений, но все же). Далее столкнулся с проблемой, что модуль неправильно переводит строки. Перевод на русский не соответствует оригиналу на английском, хотя, если отдельно переводить каждую строку, то переводит корректно. В чем проблема?

Файл `json`:

```
{
    "title": "Bitcoin Miner Marathon Digital's CFO to Retire After One Year",
    "description": "Hugh Gallagher intends to retire effective May 12.",
}
```

Мой код:

```
translator= Translator(to_lang="Russian")

with open('res.json') as file:
    templates = json.load(file)

for item in templates:

try:
    res = translator.translate(item['title'])
    print(res)

except RuntimeError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл более эффективное и простое решение. Установил библиотеку `googletrans` через команду `pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0` и далее:

```
translator = Translator()


with open('res.json') as file:
    templates = json.load(file)


for item in templates:
    result = translator.translate(item['title'], dest='ru')
    print(result.text)
```